# Generating unique random characters and saving them in array

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate random numbers and save them in an array. that' all ! but here is the point, I want to avoid duplicating and not having a number two or more times in array.

my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k, temp;

    cin >> k;

    int sym[k];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        temp = rand() % 25 + 97;

        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            while(temp == sym[j])
            {
                temp = rand() % 25 + 97; // 25 means a and 122 means z
            }
        }

        sym[i] = temp;

    }

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        cout << sym[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I still get duplicated results.

Comment: If temp == sym[1], you generate a new temp, but you do not recompare with sym[0].

Comment: You can use `a` and `z` directly to calculate your constants.

Comment: `int sym[k];` is not standard C++ when `k` is not a constant expression and this should be avoided (prefer `std::vector`, if not possible, `new`).

Answer (score 0):

Random generator doesn't mean unique generation, collisions can always happen especially when the number of generated values is high and the bounds or limits for the generation is small...

to avoid duplicated elements replace this array

```
int sym[k];
```

by a set which is a container that doesn't allow duplicate entries...

```
std::set<int>
```

after that, you need to replace the logic because looping k times does not mean having k elements in the set, so you need to do a while loop until the size of the set reaches the limit **k**

## Edit:

if you need some unsorted generated values, the instead of using a **set**, consider implementing an **unordered_set**

Comment: A `set` is going to order the elements so that might not be desired.

Comment: well he didnt specify about sort, in that case he need a unordered_set

Comment: is there anyway to do this without using set or vector ? because I'm new to c++ and don't know about these things right now.

Comment: loop the array for insertion, generate a number but before inserting it in the array verify that value is not already there.... too much work....

Answer (score 0):

I will use std::unordered_set to avoid duplicated